# Sort file based on date using Java

Tags: java, csv

I need to sort files with respect to their date . I have successfully written code which sorts the files based on last modification but help me to sort files with respect to their date. Older files should come first.

```
File dir = new File("E:\\myfiles");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    public int compare(File f1, File f2)
    {
        return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    System.out.println(files[i]);
```

my files are

```
E:\myfiles\test_20140704.csv
E:\myfiles\test_20140705.csv
E:\myfiles\test_20140703.csv
E:\myfiles\test_20140706.csv
```

Comment: You mean to sort by date in file name?

Comment: yes i need to sort files based on date present in file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something a little bit more robust than just sorting by name (which should indeed work for the sample filenames you provided), you should parse the date in the filename and sort by this date. For instance:

```
public int compare(File f1, File f2)
{
    Date d1 = fileNameToDate(f1);
    Date d2 = fileNameToDate(f2);
    return d1.compareTo(d2);
}

//caution: this static is better for performance, but may not be thread-safe
private static SimpleDateFormat DF_YYYYMMDD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

private Date fileNameToDate(File f)
{
   int pos = f.getName().lastIndexOf('_');
   if (pos < 0)
   {
     //TODO: error handling if filename is not in the correct format
   }
   String dateStr = f.getName().substring(pos + 1, pos + 1 + 8);
   try
   {
     return DF_YYYYMMDD.parse(dateStr);
   }
   catch(ParseException e)
   {
     //TODO: error handling if filename is not in the correct format        
   }
}
```

Comment: fixed. str => f.getName()

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to sort by Name of the file ( based on syntax provided in your question). Just changing the compare method would do.

```
File dir = new File("E:\\myfiles");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
   public int compare(File f1, File f2)
   {
      //return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
      return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
   }
   });
```

(Below is not relevant as per your latest comment)

File class does not support getting creation time. But Java 7 has a feature which can help

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String[] files = dir.list();
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String f1, String f2) {
            return f1.compareTo(f2);
        }
    });
```